# discord.py-rewrite - How to get a member's join ranking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, I have a `userinfo` command where I want my BOT to return some informations about a user, and one information I would like him to return is the guild join ranking, if the invocation context's guild exists.

So, if a member has created the guild, this will evaluate to `1`. If the member was the second member to join, return `2`. If the member was the third member to join, return `3`...

```py
@bot.command()
async def userinfo(ctx, *, user=None):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="User info" [...])

    ...

    embed.add_field(name="Joining rank", value=f"{SERVER JOIN RANK}/{SERVER TOTAL MEMBER COUNT})

    ...
```

Should I just use a `for` loop?

Thank you

Comment: You could do something like `sorted(guild.members, key=attrgetter('joined_at'))`.  The docs say [`joined_at`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.joined_at) is sometimes `None`  though, so you would have to come up with some way to deal with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PatrickHaugh Thank you, it worked. :)
I could make a function like that:

```py
def return_guild_join_position(user, guild):
    """Returns the guild join position of a user."""
    try:
        joins = tuple(sorted(guild.members, key=operator.attrgetter("joined_at")))
        if None in joins:
            return None
        for key, elem in enumerate(joins):
            if elem == user:
                return key + 1, len(joins)
        return None
    except:
        return None
```